# android fragment-testing dependency causes release build to fail compilation

Tags: android, android-fragments, gradle

I followed [the android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/testing) on testing fragments and added the gradle dependency as debugImplementation

```
    def fragmentVersion = "1.2.5"
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:$fragmentVersion"
    debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragmentVersion"
```

Now my release unit test task won't compile because the methods that i call to launch fragments don't exist on the release classpath..

```
> Task :app:compileReleaseUnitTestKotlin FAILED
e: C:\Users\....kt: (5, 30): Unresolved reference: testing
e: C:\Users\....kt: (58, 9): Unresolved reference: launchFragmentInContainer
e: C:\Users\....kt: (65, 9): Unresolved reference: launchFragmentInContainer
```

I understand why they make it debug only, so you don't have the testing stuff in your release build.
But how do I fix this compilation issue?

Comment: So i added `testImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragmentVersion"
` to my dependencies, and the test release compile task now works, so i guess i'll just just ignore the big red warning in my build.gradle file that says "replace with debugImplementation"

Answer (score 3):

Facing the same problem I ended up with the following **workaround**:

Use the depency as suggested in the documentation:

```
debugImplementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-testing:$fragmentVersion"
```

Then I moved all my tests that depend on lib `androidx.fragment:fragment-testing` at the `testDebug` flavor.

#### Pros:

- Can build and test both for debug and release

#### Cons:

- Lower code coverage for release :(
- Minification errors that may caught without that requirement it will not :(

This is how the project structure looks after that:

[image]

Comment: It worked for me after switch `devRelease` to `devDebug` in build variants. Thank you you saved my lots of time.